# Simultaneously call functions with different parametrs in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I found a lot of examples, but not mine. Please help me here:

I have a functions that requires a parameter (an URL) and I need to call **this** function several times (with different parameters) at the same time to get something like that:

```
 function started with param: rsync://.... (1)
 function started with param: rsync://.... (2)
 function started with param: rsync://.... (3)
 ....
 function (k) with param rsync://....has finished
 .....
 function started with param: rsync://.... (n)
 function (1) with param rsync://....has finished
 ....
 function (n) with param rsync://....has finished
```

Those functions are independent, they don't interact with any common objects or something like that (excluding imports). I need to run them at the same time (n of those functions). It doesn't matter the order how they would finish.

Comment: This is a statement of requirements rather than a question.

Comment: @NPE I need to find out tools to use, so it's just a questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Threads](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

For instance, you can use:

```
import threading
my_thread = threading.Thread(target=your_function, args=(), kwargs={})  # This can go inside a loop, providing different args each time.
my_thread.start()
```

Visit the link at top of the answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay free concerning the contents of this functions, use threads as Raydel mentions, or use [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) if the functions are supposed to be CPU bound rather than IO bound.

If your task is just to call subprocesses, you can

- start the subprocess with `sp = subprocess.Popen()`
- keep this `sp`, kind of a handle to it
- then they run in parallel
- `poll()` them until they are done
- then you know when they have finished.